# Checkbox values don't get send correctly to PHP with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

Second attempt. My last question wasn't very clear so I want to try asking for help again.. I've pasted my complete code so you guys can see what my code looks like and where the problem could be.

So I am building a basic membership website. People can register on the signup.php page. Until now this worked perfectly.Today I wanted to add a few options using checkboxes. Those checkboxes all need to get posted to their column in my table, which are of the format `ENUM('0','1'), NOT NULL and DEFAULT value is 0`.

The checkboxes are the inputs with id *'helicopter' ($heli), 'fixedwing' ($fw), 'commercial' ($com), 'glider' ($glider), 'balloon' ($bl), 'ultralight' ($ulm), 'paraglider' ($para), 'seaplane' ($sp), 'pilot' ($pilot) and 'terms' ($terms)*.

The signup page uses AJAX, PHP and MYSQL to get, validate and post the form values to the database. All the values get posted to the database correctly, but all the checkbox inputs post value 1 to the database, even if they are not clicked. So no matter if I check it or not, it always posts value 1 to the DB after submitting the form.

I have basic knowledge of PHP and MYSQL but almost no knowledge of AJAX and JAVA so I'am having a hard time finding what's wrong with my code.

**So to summarize my problem**: My normal form values get posted correctly to the database, but the checkboxes all post value 1, whether they are checked or not.

Thank you in advance!

```
<?php
session_start();
// If user is logged in, header them away
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: user.php?u=".$_SESSION["username"]);
    exit();
}
?><?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        echo 'Your username should be 3-16 characters long..';
        exit();
    }
    if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo 'Usernames must begin with a letter..';
        exit();
    }
    if ($uname_check < 1) {
        echo $username . ' is available!';
        exit();
    } else {
        echo $username . ' is taken..';
        exit();
    }
}
?><?php
// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if(isset($_POST["u"])){

    include_once("php_includes/db_conx.php");

    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    $s = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['s']);
    $b = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['b']);
    $ex = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['ex']);
    $w = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['w']);
    $bio = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['bio']);
    $heli = $_POST['heli'];
    $fw = $_POST['fw'];
    $com = $_POST['com'];
    $sp = $_POST['sp'];
    $glider = $_POST['glider'];
    $ulm = $_POST['ulm'];
    $para = $_POST['para'];
    $bl = $_POST['bl'];
    $pilot = $_POST['pilot'];
    $terms = $_POST['terms'];

    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    //--------------------------------------------

    //at least one of the following must be clicked
    $checks = $heli + $fw + $com + $sp + $glider + $ulm + $para + $bl;

    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $c == "" || $s == "" || $ex == "" || $b == ""){
        echo 'You have not completed the form yet..';
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0){ 
        echo 'The username you entered is already taken..';
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0){ 
        echo 'That email adress is already in use in our system..';
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo 'Usernames must be between 3 and 16 characters..';
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Usernames can not begin with a number..';
        exit();
    } else if($checks < 1) {
        echo 'Please select at least one licence..';
        exit();
    } else if(isset($pilot)) {
        echo 'Please verify that you are a real-life pilot..';
        exit();
    } else if(isset($terms)) {
        echo 'Please indicate that you have read our terms of use..';
        exit();
    } else {

        $p_hash = md5($p);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, country, website, bio, flighttime, bday, sex, helicopter, glider, fixedwing, seaplane, commercial, balloon, ultralight, paraglider, pilot, terms, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$c','$w','$bio','$ex','$b','$s','$heli','$glider','$fw','$sp','$com','$bl','$ulm','$para','$pilot','$terms','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
        }
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}

?>

<html>
<head>

<script>
function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'Checking...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var s = _("sex").value;
    var b = _("bday").value;
    var ex = _("experience").value;
    var w = _("website").value;
    var bio = _("bio").value;
    var heli = _("helicopter").value;
    var fw = _("fixedwing").value;
    var com = _("commercial").value;
    var sp = _("seaplane").value;
    var glider = _("glider").value;
    var ulm = _("ultralight").value;
    var para = _("paraglider").value;
    var bl = _("balloon").value;
    var pilot = _("pilot").value;
    var terms = _("terms").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || s == "" || ex == "" || b == ""){
        status.innerHTML = 'Please fill out all the form data..';
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = 'Your password fields do not match..';
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'Please wait...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("msform").innerHTML = "Thanks "+u+"! Check your email! ";
                }   ""
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&s="+s+"&b="+b+"&ex="+ex+"&w="+w+"&bio="+bio+"&heli="+heli+"&fw="+fw+"&com="+com+"&sp="+sp+"&glider="+glider+"&ulm="+ulm+"&para="+para+"&bl="+bl+"&pilot="+pilot+"&terms="+terms);
    }
}

</script>

</head>
<body>


    <form name="signupform" id="msform" onsubmit="return false;">


        <input type="text" id="username" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16" placeholder="Username" />
            <span style="width: 100%; margin-left:0" id="unamestatus"></span>
        <input style="margin-top:-20px" type="text" id="email" placeholder="Email" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88"/>
        <input type="password" id="pass1" placeholder="Password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16"  />
        <input type="password" id="pass2" placeholder="Confirm password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16"/>
        <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
              <?php include_once("template_country_list.php"); ?>
        </select>

        <textarea id="bio" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" placeholder="Bio"></textarea>
        <input type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" id="website" placeholder="Website (optional)" />

        <input type="checkbox" id="helicopter" name="helicopter" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1"> <span>Helicopter</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fixedwing" name="fixedwing" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1" > <span>Fixed Wing</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="commercial" name="commercial" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1" > <span>Commercial</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="seaplane" name="seaplane" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1" > <span>Seaplane</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="glider" name="glider" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1" > <span>Glider</span> <br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="paraglider" name="paraglider" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1" > <span>Para</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="balloon" name="balloon" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" value="1" > <span>Balloon</span><br>
        <input type="checkbox" id="ultralight" name="ultralight" onfocus="emptyElement('status')"value="1"> <span>Ultralight</span>

        <select onfocus="emptyElement('status')" id="experience">
            <option value="0-500">0-500 hours</option>
            <option value="500-1000">500-1000 hours</option>
            <option value="1000-5000">1000-5000 hours</option> 
            <option value="5000+">5000+ hours</option>
        </select>
        <select onfocus="emptyElement('status')" id="sex" >
            <option value="Male">Male</option>
            <option value="Female">Female</option>
        </select>
        <input type="date" id="bday" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">

        <input type="checkbox" id="pilot" value="1" > <span>I am a real-life pilot</span>
        <input type="checkbox" id="terms" value="1" > <span>I accept the <a target="_blank" href="legal.php"><b>the terms of use</b></a></span>

        <input type="submit" class="submit action-button" id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()" value="Sign up!" />
        <br><div id="status"></div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't set value to your checkboxes.

Comment: Yes I came across that somewhere when searching for a solution. How should I do it then? I tried something with `.prop('checked')` but that didn't work out either

Comment: what i can see is all your checkbox value are set to 1, value = "1", so?

Comment: I've set the checkbox values to 1 because I want it to post the value 1 to my DB when checked, it works when I use it in a simple PHP MYSQL form without AJAX. No I don't get any errors, the form submits as it should, the only problem I have is that all checkboxes post value 1 to my DB, even when not clicked. They should not post any value when they are not clicked, then the DB column will just be the default value 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to handle a checkbox in PHP is this...

You can give them values if you would like but it's not necessary. There is only one way to validate a checkbox in php.  This is the correct way.

```
// This checks to see if the checkbox is "checked"
if(isset($_POST['checkbox_name'])){
    // Here you can set the value manually
    $checkbox_name = 1;
    // Or you can set it to the checkbox value
    $checkbox_name = $_POST['checkbox_name'];
}else{
    // Here is where you can set the value if it is NOT "checked"
    $checkbox_name = 0;
}
```

And on the javascript side you can do this...

```
// To set the value manually based on being checked or not 
var heli = $("#helicopter").is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;

// Or get the value if checked
var heli = $("#helicopter").is(':checked') ? $("#helicopter").val() : 0;
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying it now, will let you know if it works!

Comment: @SenneVandenputte I had a typo, just fixed, sorry about that! Should have been `.is(':checked')` not `.is('checked')`

Comment: I got it to work! I first tried your PHP en javascript code but without success. Then I just changed the PHP code back like it was, `$heli = $_POST['heli'];`  and combined with your Javascript code it worked exactly as I wanted. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

try to see if the checkbox is checked instead of getting it's value :

```
var heli = document.getElementById('helicopter').checked;
```

And if you want to store the value :

```
var heli = document.getElementById('helicopter').checked ? document.getElementById('helicopter').value : 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element id to the function and then use this:

```
document.getElementById(this).click();
```

It will toggle the checkbox "checked" property. And then use the solution of VIDesignz for the PHP part.